# Turning terrible typist on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard

Or the past two or three weeks, I've been frequently "dropping characters" typing on my iPad.  Usually, it's the first character of a word.  (See the "for" starting this post?)  Of course it makes for some rather wild autocorrections.

Seems highly unlikely to be a bug, but what?  Change in the moisture content of my fingers?  But then why are letters after spaces worse than within words, and letters at the beginning of a text field worse than after a space?

Change in my muscular motions?  Seems unlikely such a major change would happen suddenly instead of gradually.  And it happens whether I have both hands/all fingers free or whether I am doing the one-finger method.

Need for warranty service on the two-month-old iPad?  Seems this would have the same objections as the others.

Comment: Do you have other iOS devices that have the same problem?  You didn't mention a specific iPad device or iOS version other than its 2-months old. I have 6 different iOS devices and I do a lot of on-screen typing. I don't have this problem on any device.

Comment: I only have one, and I did not have this problem a month ago.  Everything is up-to-date.  I think it is Air 2.

Comment: 3rd-party keyboard or the stock Apple one?  Have you tried turning off 'Check Spelling' and 'Predictive' to see if that helps?

Comment: Stock.  I haven't changed anything other than app updates.  If it wasn't caused by turning them on, how could it be fixed by turning them off?

Comment: I don't know; just trying troubleshooting steps, that's all.  I haven't experienced the issue on any of my devices so I'm ruling out a bug.  It's either a hardware issue or user error.

Comment: Must be a hardware issue then.  User error wouldn't suddenly start happening on one out of three words.  Still, hard to imagine a hardware issue that would show a preference to the first letters of words.

Comment: It seems since the last iOS update both my iPhone 6 and iPad Mini are very slow to respond to touch input. I wonder if that is manifesting in your case as dropping the first character of words.

Comment: Possiblity perhaps